# How to display count of media files in React-Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I need to display the count of media files including videos, images and other files. How do i count the values and which method to use in react native?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CameraRoll getPhotos() method,

```
CameraRoll.getPhotos(params);
```

please refer to the documentation here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll